# CakePHP mask integer to text

Tags: php, database, forms, cakephp

I am building a CRM, and when an "opportunity" is at a certain stage, it represents a probability. For example. At stage "won" the probability is at "100"

Right now I have it so that in the controller, add form and edit form view it is as follows:

```
'0'=>'Lost'
, '5' => 'Customer Contacted'
, '10' => 'WDS Sent'
, '20' => 'WDS Received'
, '30' => 'Proposal Sent'
, '60' => 'Negotiations'
, '100' => 'Won'
```

The result is that there is a dropdown of the text and saves it as an integer in the database. This is good. The problem is when I want to show the value in a view it comes back as the integer. But I need to be able to show the text when needed.

When calling the value I do

```
echo $thisOpportunity['Opportunity']['opportunity_stage_assigned'];
```

The kicker is that I also need the integer so that I can do math with the probability. For example. if WDS SENT then 10 * [amount] /100

I have looked at http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/26/bitmasked-using-bitmasks-in-cakephp/ but can't seem to figure out how to make it work for me.

Any help counts as I am stuck.

Comment: Those are not bitmasks, those are random numbers. Use [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/) then.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you just use integer as the array index.

```
0=>'Lost'
, 5 => 'Customer Contacted'
, 10 => 'WDS Sent'
, 20 => 'WDS Received'
, 30 => 'Proposal Sent'
, 60 => 'Negotiations'
, 100 => 'Won'
```